# What is $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \mathbb{R}^k$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \mathbb{R}^k$ where $k <n$?

Comment: It's $\mathbb R^n \setminus \mathbb R^k$....

Comment: @John Can you explain as  $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \mathbb{R}^k = \{(x_1,...x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n | ......\}$?

Comment: Oh I see your point. Normally $\mathbb R^k \subset \mathbb R^n$ is given by the inclusion $(x_1, \cdots, x_k) \to (x_1, \cdots, x_k, 0, \cdots , 0)$. But you better check your notations. Its not universal.

Comment: @John So $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \mathbb{R}^k = \{(0_1,...0_k,x_{k+1},...x_n) | x_{k+1},...x_n \neq 0\}$?

Comment: $\mathbb R^n \setminus \mathbb R^k = \{ (x_1, \cdots, x_n)| x_j \neq 0$ for some $j=k+1, \cdots n\}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can understand, the issue here is: how do you interpret the relation $\mathbb{R}^k \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, when $k<n$? Let us see in the easy case $k=1$ and $n=2$: $\mathbb{R}^1$ is the set of real numbers, while $\mathbb{R}^2=\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. These two sets are different in nature, so that $\mathbb{R}^k \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ can't be a standard inclusion.

However, $\mathbb{R}$ can be identified with many subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$. The basic identification is $\mathbb{R} \approx \{(x,0) \mid x \in \mathbb{R}\}$, but we could also imagine $\mathbb{R} \approx \{(x,*)\mid x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ for any $* \in \mathbb{R}$. We could even think that $\mathbb{R} \approx \{(x,mx)\mid x \in \mathbb{R}\}$, with $m \in \mathbb{R}$ fixed. Or even $\mathbb{R} \approx S^1 \setminus \{(0,1)\}$.

So, what is $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \mathbb{R}$? My opinion is that this is almost meaningless (and I've never written such a thing in a research paper). I understand that there are situations where you need a chain like $\mathbb{R}^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3 \subset \ldots$, but these situations are easily solved by stating a convention. Your favorite identification usually works well enough.

Comment: Excellent answer.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \mathbb{R}^k$ means every element from $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is not in $\mathbb{R}^k$.
For example: $\mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$ means every element from the complex plane (which is, at all, $\mathbb{R}^2$) that is not in $\mathbb{R}$ (in other words, every complex number $z$ for which $\Im(z) \neq 0$).

Answer (score 0):

Start from easy examples: for $n=2, k=1$ you have $\mathbb R^2\setminus\mathbb R$ that is mainly "the plane without the $x$-axis". But in general, as a set, you can consider that as the plane witout a line.

Similarly take $n=3, k=1$: $\mathbb R^3\setminus\mathbb R$. This is the $3$-D space without a whole line... not different the case $n=3, k=2$, i.e. the $3$-D space without a plane... and so on.

But if you work simply with sets, notice that, for example $\mathbb R$ is in bijection with the union of two different lines (take for example the $x$- axis and the $y$- axis), hence the writing $\mathbb R^2\setminus\mathbb R$ could refer to the plane without the axis. Or, also, again $\mathbb R$ is in bijection with a numerable copies of itself, $\mathbb R^2\setminus\mathbb R$ could be thinked as the plane without the grill formed by the vertical lines passing for $(k,0)$ and the horizontal lines passing for $(0,k)$, as $k\in\mathbb Z$.

However the standard meaning of $\mathbb R^2\setminus\mathbb R$ is the plane without a line (mostly the $x$-axis).